# Parse HTML input value to php over javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, input, chart.js

I have the following scenario running:

graph.html --> uses ChartJS to display a line graph and imports graph.js

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ChartJS - LineGraph</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="input" id="subject" value="">
</form>
<!-- javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/graph.js"></script>
</body>
```

graph.js --> makes a AJAX call on the graph.php file to get the data and format it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
url : "/graph.php",
type : "GET",
success : function(data){
console.log(data);
...
var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartdata
  });
```

graph.php --> Calls mysql database to get data

```
$var = $_GET['input'];
$query = sprintf("SELECT $var FROM wetter");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

I like to change the SELECT statement in the php-file by entering a new SELECT-statement in a input field of the .html file. If I put the normal $_GET[] method into the .php it will not find the input value from the .html file.

How can I parse the input value from the .html to the .php when there is a Javascript file in between?
Do I need to change something in my scenario?

Comment: I can't see your coding attempt for some reason.  Off-topic: Why isn't my code working?

Comment: I thought it is way to much coding to post it here, therefore I wanted to talk about the principle on how to do it in gerneral

Comment: We only need to see the broken scripts, not every file on your server.

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example of your code like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use a white list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've shown, it doesn't look like you're passing the input value along with your ajax request, you should add something like

```
$.ajax({
   url : "/graph.php",
   type : "GET",
   data : {input : $('#subject').val()}, <-- added this
   success : function(data){
```

In order to be able to see the value in `$_GET['input']` on the php side.

But there is another issue I believe, your ajax request is sent as soon as your document is ready (`$(document).ready(function(){`), but at that time your input is most likely going to be empty. You probably want to change it to `$('form[name="form"]').on('submit',function(event){event.preventDefault(); ...})`, assuming your form only does that one thing (display a graph according to the input)

Comment: thanks a lot, but how can I access the data in the php then? $var_name =$_GET['subject'];  seems not to work.

Comment: I had apostrophes around 'input' in the ajax data, my apologies... To get it in php, if you defined `data : {input : $('#subject').val()}` it should be in  `$_GET['input'] `, just replace `input`  by `subject` in the ajax data if you want the key to be `$_GET['subject']`